# Raspberry Pi 4 stops boot sequence until I press Enter

Tags: boot, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 with the kali linux os(64 bit version). I've added the ssh file to the boot folder in order to enable it from the beginning.

However, I cannot connect to the pi via ssh because port 22 seems to be closed:
[image: Console output ssh]

When I run an nmap scan it tells me that all ports are closed:
[image: Console output nmap]

I connected the pi to a display via hdmi to see if it boots correctly and it always stops the boot sequence without an error before entering the GUI/console until I press 'ENTER'.

After that I can connect to the pi via ssh without any problems.

How can I continue the boot sequence automatically?

Comment: What's shown on the screen at the point the boot sequence is paused? There must be some reason for the hiatus

Comment: @roaima unfortunately, this problem is a bit older and i solved it back then. I believe the problem was that the system performed a file system check and waited for the user to admit it. I think I solved the problem with omiting file system checks in the fstab file, but im not totally sure since this problem is from the past. Anyone stumbling across this i would suggest to dig deeper inte file system checks and fstab